# Dealing with missing argument and I18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization

Given that I have a key with this translation key

```
t('my.key', :url => @url)
```

And translation in many language:

```
key: "Click %{url}"
```

I do the following change:

```
t('my.key', :link => @link)

key: "Click %{url}"
```

The keys are translated by the community, I have quite a few. We only maintain english locale.

Now ofcourse, my test go red, because if this view render in any other language than english without updating all the other keys, it will return:

```
missing interpolation argument in "Click %{url}" ({:link=>"..."} given)
(ActionView::TemplateError)
```

What's the lazy-programmer way to solve that? Rake task to remove the keys? Monkey patch I18n to rescue to :en?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing changed in the localizable section of the string.

The %{...} is never translated, it is just a variable name.

So it is safe to change %{url} to %{link} it in all languages
(making sure to not damage the strings by using an editor that messes up the encoding though).

It is a bit like changing html tags:

```
   <p>Click <b>Print</b> to whatever</p>
```

change to:

```
   <p>Click <i>Print</i> to whatever</p>
```

Comment: we maintain only the english locale, so we never edit other locale by hands, it would mess with the translation frontend we use.